# bootstrap conflict hamburger menu display

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

**Why bootstrap  has conflict with hamburger menu display?**

Hamburger menus open and close button is on left, but when I add bootstrap css line, hamburger close button float to right position!
and when I remove that line is okey.
How Should I Fix This?

**Code:**

```js
function openNavbar () {
 document.querySelector("#navbar").style.width="100%";
 document.querySelectorAll(".open")[0].style.opacity = 0;
}
function closeNavbar () {
 document.querySelector("#navbar").style.width="0";
 document.querySelectorAll(".open")[0].style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1096658/pexels-photo-1096658.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940") center/cover no-repeat;
 font: bold 1rem Consolas;
}

.open, .close{
 display: inline-block;
 padding:30px 0 0 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size:2rem;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .5s;
}

.overlay{
 position: fixed;
 width: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 opacity: .7;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 transition: .5s;
}

.overlay-content{
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay-content a {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 padding:10px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .3s;
 position: relative;

}
.overlay-content a:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 3px;
    background:#fff;
    transition: .3s;
    display: block;

}
.overlay-content a:hover{
 color:#ff9f1a;
}

.overlay-content a:hover:after{
 width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

        <span class="open" onclick="openNavbar()">&#9776; Menu</span>
        <div id="navbar" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeNavbar()" class="close">&#9932;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Services</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Contact</a>
        </div>
        </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your close button on the left when the menu is open, you will have to set `float: none;` to prevent the default `float: right;` set by the `close` class helper from bootstrap (more infos [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/close-icon/)).

So at your `a` link, apply `style="float:none;"` like so :

`<a style="float:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeNavbar()" class="close">&#9932;</a>`

or you can use bootstrap's `float-none` helper like this :

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeNavbar()" class="close float-none">&#9932;</a>` and the close button will remain on the left.

Example below :

```js
function openNavbar () {
 document.querySelector("#navbar").style.width="100%";
 document.querySelectorAll(".open")[0].style.opacity = 0;
}
function closeNavbar () {
 document.querySelector("#navbar").style.width="0";
 document.querySelectorAll(".open")[0].style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1096658/pexels-photo-1096658.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940") center/cover no-repeat;
 font: bold 1rem Consolas;
}

.open, .close{
 display: inline-block;
 padding:30px 0 0 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size:2rem;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .5s;
}

.overlay{
 position: fixed;
 width: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 opacity: .7;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 transition: .5s;
}

.overlay-content{
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay-content a {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 padding:10px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .3s;
 position: relative;

}
.overlay-content a:after{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 3px;
    background:#fff;
    transition: .3s;
    display: block;

}
.overlay-content a:hover{
 color:#ff9f1a;
}

.overlay-content a:hover:after{
 width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

        <span class="open" onclick="openNavbar()">&#9776; Menu</span>
        <div id="navbar" class="overlay">
        <a style="float:none;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="closeNavbar()" class="close">&#9932;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Services</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">About</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(o);">Contact</a>
        </div>
        </div>



</body>
```